# PHP dynamic categories function concat not working

Tags: php

Im working on a project that has categories, subcategories, sub subcategories, etc. The user can create them. I want to display them on a table.
I use this function, but the return only gives me the parents categories (parent_id = 0). It misses the subcategories, and the sub sub ...
If I put a var_dump, it shows me that the concatenation is working, but when the function founds another category parent, loses the other data. What am I doing wrong, please help.

I want to return a variable that contains all the categories and subcategories.

```
function categoryTree($catsSubcats = "", $parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = ""){ var_dump($catsSubcats);

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM categorias_compra WHERE parent_id = $parent_id");
        $stmt -> execute();
        $respuesta = $stmt -> fetchAll(); 

        if($respuesta){
            foreach($respuesta as $key => $value){
                $catsSubcats = $catsSubcats . $sub_mark.$value['nombre'].'<br>'; 
                categoryTree($catsSubcats, $value['id'], $sub_mark.str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5));
            }
            return $catsSubcats;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you expecting this function to write data to your table? There are no `INSERT` or `UPDATE` queries and it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: You're not using the result of the recursive call. Did you mean to append that to the output string?

Comment: Like `$catsSubcats .= categoryTree(...)`

Comment: I want to append all the categories and subcategories  to one output string.

Comment: Thank you very much "Don't Panic"... yes, that's what I wanted

Comment: Off-Topic: Your code is vulnerable to sql injection. If you already went and used the `prepare` function, then instead of putting the `$parent_id` directly in the string, use the `?` placeholder and pass the variable through the `execute` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the return value in the recursion.
Probably you want something like this:

```
function categoryTree($parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = ""){ 
        $catsSubcats='';
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM categorias_compra WHERE parent_id = $parent_id");
        $stmt -> execute();
        $respuesta = $stmt -> fetchAll(); 

        if($respuesta){
            foreach($respuesta as $key => $value){
                $catsSubcats .= $sub_mark.$value['nombre'].'<br>'; 
                $catsSubcats .= categoryTree($value['id'], $sub_mark.str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5));
            }
        }
        return $catsSubcats;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the result of the recursive call isn't being used, but it looks like if you append it to the string, you'll end up with a lot of repetition.

I think you don't need to pass the main string to the recursive call. That's what will cause the repeated results. You need to append only the result of the recursive call, not that result plus everything you already had at that point.

Also, if you pass your prepared statement recursively, you should be able to reuse it instead of preparing the same thing repeatedly.

I can't really test it, but I think this will work better.

```
function categoryTree($parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = "", $stmt = null) {
    if (!$stmt) {
        // only prepare the first time, then pass the prepared statement to subsequent calls
        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM categorias_compra WHERE parent_id = ?");
    }

    // bind $parent_id to the ? placeholder in the prepared statement
    $stmt->execute([$parent_id]);

    $respuesta = $stmt->fetchAll();

    // initialize the result of each call to an empty string
    $catsSubcats = "";

    if ($respuesta) {

        // you can also move this before the loop so it only has to execute once
        $sub_mark .= str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5);

        foreach ($respuesta as $key => $value) {
            $catsSubcats .= $sub_mark.$value['nombre'].'<br>';
            $catsSubcats .= categoryTree($value['id'], $sub_mark, $stmt);
        }
    }

    // always return a string
    return $catsSubcats;
}
```